# How can i create a route with underscore in next 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to create a URL address that start with an **underscore** but i cant because next.js dacument said it was a private folder!
how can i do it?
example: `/shop/_t-shirt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 13, Next.js mentioned a way that you can create URL segments that start with an underscore

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/colocation

> You can create URL segments that start with an underscore by prefixing the folder name with **%5F** (the URL-encoded form of an underscore): %5FfolderName.

so you can do it:

```
/app
  /shop
  /%5Ft-shirt
    page.tsx
```